# How to prevent the "config.txt" file is empty after each start

Tags: pi-3, config.txt

I use a specific screen with my raspberry pi 3 that requires a command to set the resolution to him, otherwise it displays nothing. It works fine, the problem is that after each start the file "config.txt" is empty and I have to manually rewrite the command with another pc if I want to use it. It's tedious .. Anyone know how to prevent the automatic deletion of the file content "config.txt"? Thank you
Tested with raspbian, ubuntu mate, same problem.

Code i put in config.txt after each start :

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
```

Comment: What automatic deletion?  I've not heard of any automatic deletion of /boot/config.txt.  Doing so makes no sense.  Are you using NOOBS?

Comment: @joan thanks for reply, I'm using ubuntu mate, tried with rasp and same problem. config.txt is not exactly deleted, it is rather empty, when I open it on another pc after using

Comment: There is no reason to delete the contents of /boot/config.txt.  Are you sure you are editing the file and saving the edits correctly?

Comment: @joan Indeed its really strange, but yes, i save file correctly because my screen work, but after reboot the file is empty so my screen no work more..

Comment: That's why I wondered if you were using a "boot manager" like NOOBS.

Comment: @joan, i dont know i'm a noob ahah, but i think i dont use that

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After installing Raspbian using NOOBs, the screen was upside down so I used `sudo nano /boot/config.txt` and added the following:

```
lcd_rotate=2
```

After rebooting, the screen was still upside down and when I edited the file, it appeared empty, but the cat command and the Windows text editor showed that it had the original content.

Later I tried `sudo vi /boot/config.txt` and it showed below:

```
E325: Attention
Found a swap file by name '/boot/.config.txt.swp' ...
(1) Another program may be editing the same file ...
(2) An edit session for this file crashed ...
```

Then it displayed the file with `^M` (in blue) at the end of last 3 line as follows:

```
^M

# NOOBS Auto-generated Settings:^M

hdmi_force_hotplug=1^M
```

Later I deleted the swap file and re-edited the config file (using nano) and rebooted and this time it worked. I wonder if I have a marginal SD card (Samsung 32 GB).

Answer (score 0):

I just had same thing, 
`sudo nano boot/config.txt`  brings up an empty file to edit.

I changed into the boot directory and there were two files

- config.txt
- config.txt~

From within the boot directory, config.txt edited fine.

So what I did was

```
cd /boot
```

and then

```
sudo nano config.txt
```

At some point I suspect I've made a duplicate file.

Comment: That's a backup file from vim, mg or emacs. Or perhaps nano.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the file was edited with an editor (under Windows maybe?) that is configured to use 'MS-Windows/DOS' line endings (CRLF) instead of 'Unix' line endings (LF).

Either configure the editor to use 'Unix' line endings or use the **dos2unix** or **unix2dos** utility to convert between the two. To work properly the line endings should be 'Unix' line endings (LF)

Comment: Why does should a CRLF empty a file on boot up? The boot loader may fail to read it properly but it will not empty it.

Comment: You are right, it should not empty the file. In fact my answer fits better to the answer given by @jraustin1 (where the display of ^M is explicitly mentioned)